# How to configure the directory structure differently in Jenkins when cloning the repository from git?

Tags: git, jenkins

I need help in setting up the different directory structure in Jenkins than git.

#### Git structure:

```
root->A_dir ->A_file1
            ->A_file2
            ->....
            ->A_fileN
     ->B_dir->C_dir ->C_file1
                    ->C_file2
                    ->....
                    ->C_fileN
            ->B_file1
            ->B_file2
            ->....
            ->B_fileN
     ->f1.txt
     ->f2.txt
     ->f3.txt
```

#### Desired Jenkins structure:

```
root->A_file1          
     ->B_dir->C_dir ->C_file1
                    ->C_file2
                    ->....
                    ->C_fileN
     ->f1.txt
     ->f2.txt
     ->f3.txt
```

Comment: I dont know of a way to do this, and hopefully someone points out a way,  however because you are using jenkins, why not have a pre-build step that does what you need?

Comment: Sorry i am new to jenkins, what does pre-build step means can you please elaborate.